# Replacing deprecated NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification in OSX 10.11+

Tags: macos, cocoa, fsevents, nsworkspace

I am trying to monitor file changes, as well as identify the application that performed them, on OSX. `NSWorkspace` provides the `NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification` event, which is perfect for my needs, but [it is deprecated in OSX 10.11](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification) with no suggested replacement in the docs. Is there a direct replacement available?

I am aware of `FSEvents` streams, but for this particular use case the above seems to have a much simpler usage pattern. As far as I currently understand it, fsevent monitoring at the root level is expensive, and monitoring file changes requires explicit caching of directory listings.

Comment: `NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification` never informed your app about file operations performed by other apps. From the docs you linked (emphasis added): "Posted when a file operation has been performed **in the receiving app**." It is only posted when your app uses `-performFileOperation:source:destination:files:tag:`, not even for general file operations.

Comment: Ah.. Oh dear. My apologies - I should have realised. Thanks for the info - I will pursue fsevents. Not sure on the etiquette here - I assume I leave this question be, for posterity?